# Convert Roman to Int

Tags: python, optimization, converting, roman-numerals

I made a function that converts Roman letters to integers. But I'm not happy with it, as I feel like I used too much code for a such a simple task. Any suggestion on how I can minimize it?

```
values = (('M',  1000),
         ('CM', 900),
         ('D',  500),
         ('CD', 400),
         ('C',  100),
         ('XC', 90),
         ('L',  50),
         ('XL', 40),
         ('X',  10),
         ('IX', 9),
         ('V',  5),
         ('IV', 4),
         ('I',  1))

def RomanToInt(year):
    result = 0
    boom = []
    for i in range(len(year)):
        for letter, value in values:
            if year[i] == letter:
                boom.append(value)
    boom.append(0)
    for i in range(len(year)):
        if boom[i] >= boom[i+1]:
            result = result + boom[i]
        else:
            result = result - boom[i]
    return result
```

Comment: You may want to check out Mark Pilgrim's code:
http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docutils/utils/roman.py

Comment: I see Mark is using `variable[index:index]` to match each value. Any way you can give me a reference or documentation for that? I've never heard of something like `variable[0:2]`

Comment: @TonyFire look up "slice"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few notes:

1. A tuple of two-tuples is an odd structure for `values`, if you used a dictionary `{'M': 1000, ...}` you could avoid the loop over `values` and just use `boom.append(values[year[i]])`;
2. There is no point including e.g. `CM` in `values`, as there is no way `year[i]` (a single character) would ever be equal to those `letter`s;
3. `values` should be defined inside the function, perhaps as a default argument, as it's not needed in any other scope;
4. `for i in range(len(year)): ... year[i]` is generally unpythonic, use `for letter in year:` instead (where you need `i` *and* `i+1`, you can use `zip(l, l[1:])` to get pairs);
5. `boom` is not a very good name for the list, as it doesn't really explain what should be in it (something like `numbers` might be better) and there's no need to limit yourself to `year` inputs; and
6. Per [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the function should be called `roman_to_int`, and you should consider adding a [docstring](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

With the above fixes:

```
def roman_to_int(roman, values={'M': 1000, 'D': 500, 'C': 100, 'L': 50, 
                                'X': 10, 'V': 5, 'I': 1}):
    """Convert from Roman numerals to an integer."""
    numbers = []
    for char in roman:
        numbers.append(values[char]) 
    total = 0
    for num1, num2 in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]):
        if num1 >= num2:
            total += num1
        else:
            total -= num1
    return total + num2
```

You could also consider simplifying with a list comprehension, and adding error handling for the following cases:

- `roman` is an empty string `""`; and
- `roman` contains characters not in `values`.

Comment: The problem I had with dictionary is that the values are unordered. I have a `int_to_roman` function also that checks the intergers in order of `values`

Comment: Does the solution work for one-letter roman numbers?

Comment: @Heikki apparently not, when I try it throws an error. Perhaps you can work out why?

Comment: `zip(numbers, numbers[1:])` refers to an empty number and then `num2` is never assigned. Adding `num2 = numbers[0]` in front of `for ... zip(...)` helped.

Comment: for single Romans you will get an error. Please add this to the return statement: return numbers[0] if total == 0 else total + num2

Comment: @laza what do you mean *"single Romans"*? What error?

Comment: @laza reading back through the comments that has been discussed before. The point here was not to provide a perfect implementation, I'll leave it as-is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right! : )

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly minimal.

```
def get_int_from_roman_numeral_string(r):
    x = {'M': 1000, 'D': 500, 'C': 100, 'L': 50, 'X': 10, 'V': 5, 'I': 1}
    return sum([x[i] if x[i] >= x[j] else -x[i] for i, j in zip(r, r[1:])]) + x[j]
```

- As `jonrsharpe` has pointed out we can minimize your tuple-of-tuples
  (`values`) by removing the roman numeral strings of length two. Not
  knowing much at all about Roman numerals, I was curious how this
  worked. After reading the [Roman numerals Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Alternative_forms) it
  became clear that there are a couple of ways to evaluate a string of
  Roman numeral symbols. The type of Roman numeral strings that your
  code can process must utilize [subtractive notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtractive_notation). A familiar
  example is `IV == 4`. The logic for subtractive notation is embedded
  in the conditional expression found in your final for loop.
- Of course I wouldn't recommend usually writing code like the final line of my function. But as you were curious how to reduce your code length, I obliged my inner code golfer.